# Drupal 8 - change node display design

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, drupal-8

Any idea how I can change the display design of the nodes from a specific content type (e.g. Articles)?

I saw that for earlier version there was a module, however it seems its not working under drupal8:
https://www.drupal.org/project/node_form_template

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=drupal+8+theme+suggestions+content+type

Answer (score 0):

> A small module which allows you to change the view mode of an entity.
>
> This module provides a new field type "View mode selector", so just go
>   to "Manage fields" and create a field of that type and choose between
>   a "select list" and a "radio buttons" widget. When you choose "radio
>   buttons" it is possible to upload an icon which will be displayed
>   instead of the view mode name.

You should definitely read this-

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/193327